# Read Multiple Files In Java

Tags: java, filenames, readfile

I want to read multiple files into Java at once. File names are like:

- nnnnn_UM2012.txt
- ghkjdf_UM2045.txt
- erey_UM2189.txt
- ....

There are over 1,000 files and I do not want to write all files names in Java one by one, using code similar to the following one:

```
String fileNames = {"nnnnn_UM2012.txt","ghkjdf_UM2045.txt","erey_UM2189.txt", …}
```

Maybe the filenames should be read in reverse order. How can I do that?

Comment: The answer below shows how to get all the file names in a folder. If you have a question about reversing the order, please clarify.

Answer (score 5):

To get all files in a folder (sub-folders are included in the list of files):

```
    // get all files in the folder
    final File folder = new File(".");
    final List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles());
```

To get all files in a folder, excluding sub-folders:

```
    // get all files in the folder excluding sub-folders
    final File folder = new File(".");
    final List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isFile();
        }
    }));
```

To sort the list of files into reverse case-sensitive order:

```
    // sort the files into reverse order
    Collections.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            return o2.getName().compareTo(o1.getName());
        }
    });
```

To sort the list of files into reverse case-insensitive order:

```
    // sort the files into reverse order ignoring case
    Collections.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            return o2.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o1.getName());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [listFiles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) method to obtain all the files in the folder.

Comment: This link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Answer (score 0):

```
File rep = new File("path to rep");
File[] list = rep.listFiles();
ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    filenames.add(list[i].getName());
}
```

I guess it can be a solution to your problem.

Comment: Better written as `Arrays.asList(rep.listFiles());` which becomes `asList(rep.listFiles());` with a static import.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below approach if all the files are in a single directory.
Get a reference to the directory by providing its fully qualified path and then use the `list()` function get all the file names into a `String` array inside the directory.

After this step you can sort the files according to the way you want (For e.g. by its name,length,etc..).